# Adding tick marks and line on barplot

Tags: rstudio

[image]I need help adding tick marks to my barplot. I would like an X-axis with tick marks in intervals of 100. I would also like to add a vertical red line at X=1350. How can I add that to the following code:

```
 H <- c(1350, 1436) # Create the data for the chart, cont3.#
  M <- c(
   "Target 
   Attendance",
   "Actual 
   Attendance"
   )
   c <-barplot(H, col =c("slategray3","dodgerblue4" ),
        names.arg = M, horiz = TRUE, 
        family="Arial", border = NA,  
        xlim = range(0,1600),
        axes = TRUE, las=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the `axis()` and `abline()` functions to modify the base graphics:

```
barplot(H, col =c("slategray3","dodgerblue4" ),
                         names.arg = M, horiz = TRUE, 
                         family="Arial", border = NA,  
                         xlim = range(0,1600),
                         axes = FALSE, las=1) 
axis(1, at=seq(0, 1500, 100))
abline(v=1350, col="red")
```

Add the "lwd=" option to the `abline` function to change the line's width.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. So when I replicate this on my computer I can't see the scale. Also, I notice that 1,000 tick mark is missing on your version and the Y labels are partially cutoff. Any suggestions on how I can fix this

Comment: Unless the plot window is really wide, plotting the intervals by 100 is maybe too many. If spacing between tick marks is too small, then some of the labels will get dropped. Widen the plot window or try reducing the axis' text size with cex.axis= .